# Laravel Eloquent Many-To-Many Query Producing Extra null WHERE clause

Tags: eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, where-clause, laravel-5.7

I'm using Eloquent to produce results from a query comprised of three tables:

```
photos              (id)
photos_to_photosets (photo_id, photoset_id)
photosets           (id)
```

My models have their many-to-many relationships defined as:

```php
class Photo extends Model
{
    public function photosets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PhotoSet::class, 'photos_to_photo_sets');
    }
}
```

And

```php
class PhotoSets extends Model
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Photo::class, 'photos_to_photo_sets');
    }

}
```

Now, to fetch results I'm forced to use the following Eloquent code:

```php
$photoData = $this->photoSets->photos()
                             ->orWhere('photo_set_id', '=', $id)
                             ->get();
```

This produces the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `photos_to_photo_sets` 
     ON `photos`.`id` = `photos_to_photo_sets`.`photo_id` 
WHERE `photos_to_photo_sets`.`photo_set_id` is null 
     OR `photo_set_id` = ?
```

This query works, but I can't seem to remove `` WHERE `photos_to_photo_sets`.`photo_set_id` is null `` from the query.

I've tried to just use `->where('photo_set_id', '=', $id)` but the null clause still remains; even worse it produces the following WHERE clause:

```sql
... WHERE `photos_to_photo_sets`.`photo_set_id` IS NULL 
        AND `photo_set_id` = ?
```

Is there any way, utilizing Eloquent, to remove this null WHERE clause segment?

Ideally, I'd like to end up with the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `photos_to_photo_sets` 
     ON `photos`.`id` = `photos_to_photo_sets`.`photo_id` 
WHERE `photo_set_id` = ?
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**

Based off @Jonas Staudenmeir's answer, the null WHERE clause has been removed.

To achieve this, I set the photoSet's model ID prior to running the query. The resulting code was:

```
$this->photoSets->id = $photoset_id;

$photoData = $this->photoSets->photos()->get();
```

Which produced:

```
SELECT * FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `photos_to_photo_sets` 
     ON `photos`.`id` = `photos_to_photo_sets`.`photo_id` 
WHERE `photo_set_id` = ?
```

Comment: What is `$this->photoSets`?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir Sorry, I didn't paste the controller  where the query is being executed. In the controller, I'm using Dependency Injection for my PhotoSet model.

Comment: Looks like the injected model is empty or doesn't have an `id`. What's the result of `dd($this->photoSets->getAttributes());`?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir Running that comes back with an empty result set. I'm confused, what do you mean by: "injected model is empty or doesn't have an id"?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir You we're spot on! I had to set the id of ```$this->photoSet->id =``` to an actual value prior to running my query. I didn't have to add ```protected $attributes = ['id'= x]``` though. Thank you! I can accept that as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injected model doesn't have an `id`:

```php
$this->photoSet->id = $id;
```

Then you don't need the additional constraint:

```php
$photoData = $this->photoSets->photos;
```